# fglrx drivers cause blank luks encryption password screen on boot, on Linux Mint Petra 16

Tags: linux, encryption, linux-mint, luks, fglrx

I recently did a new install of Linux Mint 16 Petra on my main desktop, and used the full disk encryption option from the installer. The installation went smoothly, and the encryption password prompt displayed normally before boot (immediately after selection an entry from Grub and well before the MDM login screen). This was with the open source x.org graphics drivers.

Being a gamer though and requiring some of the features of AMD's proprietary drivers, I installed the fglrx drivers through Mint's System Settings. Now when I boot I no long get the password entry prompt, but simply a blank screen. However, if I type in the password blindly and press Enter, the system still boots normally, so it seems obvious it's a display problem.

I've tried various methods of installing fglrx, including through the System Settings, apt-get, and manually using the latest drivers (both the stable and beta) from AMD, all with the same result.

Does anyone have any ideas how to get the password prompt to show? At the very least, I'd accept a text-mod prompt such as when I enter rescue mode through Grub.

Answer (score 2):

The kernel seems to have a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cryptsetup/+bug/1375435).

My workaround is to disable a splash during Linux boot. One needs to edit a file:

`sudo emacs -nw /etc/default/grub`

Modify line to:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""`

And then call:

`sudo update-grub`

Comment: Just removing the `splash` option from `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` is enough, the remaining options (usually `quiet`) can remain.

Answer (score 0):

What fixed it for me:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Look for the line :

```
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
```

Just underneath write the line :

```
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=auto
```

Comment: It would be good to explain how this solves the problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

Then select number 0 "no-logo".

It turns the graphical prompt off and shows a classic text-based one.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it didn't work. I selected the no-logo option (#2 on my system), but all it did was change the Grub to text-based. The encryption password comes after Grub but before the rest of the boot, and that apparently is still trying to use a graphical mode.

Comment: There is no "no-logo" option on my system (Ubuntu 15.04).